# How to store CSV files to Google Drive using Python

Tags: python, api, csv, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to upload CSV files from my desktop to Google Drive using the Google Drive API and Python. I have completed the set up through the developers site https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python and am confused on the next steps.

I want to upload the CSV files, and DO NOT want to convert the files to google spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

The docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) imply that your file will not be converted unless you specify a `mimeType` in file metadata.

So you should be able to do:

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'My Report'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/report.csv',
                    mimetype='text/csv',
                    resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                media_body=media,
                                fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm getting a permission error right now. googleapiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 "Insufficient Permission"> My source is SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I get the following exception:  ```NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined```.  Any Ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: @Fergus search for line containing discovery.build('drive'.......) the variable holding this value is probably what you are looking for